# iterating over multi dimensional array for a menu

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

Hello I have a menu made in codeigniter. but I also want this to have submenu's

Therefore I get an array and go through it with a foreach loop.

```
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($menu_item as $menu =>& $key): ?>    
            <li><?php echo anchor($menu, $key, $this->uri->slash_segment(1, 'leading') == $menu ? 'class="active"' : '') ?></li>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </ul>
```

Now the problem is that this works great if its just one menu without submenu's but when I get an array like this

```
$menu_item = array(
    '/' => 'Home',
    '/about' => 'About',
    '/foo' => 'boo',
    '/contact' => 'contact',
    'test' => array(
               'foo' => 'boo'
              ),

    'test2' => 'foo2'
);
```

Than it doesn't work anymore. How can I loop through everything and output it as a good menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of the other answers is true, but they generate invalid DOM structure, so I decided to fix it.

You can make a `helper` file and put the `drawMenu()` function inside. So, you'll be able to call the function as much as you need.

```
$menu = array(
    '/'        => 'Home',
    '/about'   => 'About',
    '/foo'     => 'boo',
    '/contact' => 'contact',
    'test'     => array(
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'baz' => 'qux'
    ),
    'test2' => 'foo2'
);

function drawMenu($menu)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();

    $output = '';
    foreach ($menu as $key => $value) {
        $output .= "<li>";
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $output .= anchor('#', $key);
            $output .= PHP_EOL."<ul>".PHP_EOL;
            $output .= drawMenu($value);
            $output .= "</ul>".PHP_EOL."</li>".PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            $output .= anchor($key, $value, $CI->uri->slash_segment(1, 'leading') == $key ? 'class="active"' : '');
            $output .= "</li>".PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

$html = drawMenu($menu);
echo '<ul>'. $html .'</ul>';
```

***Side-note:** Usage `PHP_EOL` constant is arbitrary, it just makes generated DOM more readable.*

---

**Update:**

I improved the `drawMenu()` functionality, now you can add a URL address for the headers of sub-menus:

```
$menu = array(
    '/'        => 'Home',
    '/about'   => 'About',
    '/foo'     => 'boo',
    '/contact' => 'contact',
    'test'     => array(
        'foo' => 'bar'
    ),
    'This is Test2|/url/to/test2' => array(
        'baz' => 'qux'
    )
);
```

You can add the URL after `|` separator.

```
function drawMenu($menu)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();

    $output = '';
    foreach ($menu as $key => $value) {
        $output .= "<li>";

        if (is_array($value)) {

            if (strpos($key, '|') !== false) {
                $param = explode('|', $key);
                $output .= anchor($param[1], $param[0]);
            } else {
                $output .= anchor('#', $key);
            }

            $output .= PHP_EOL."<ul>".PHP_EOL;
            $output .= drawMenu($value);
            $output .= "</ul>".PHP_EOL."</li>".PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            $output .= anchor($key, $value, $CI->uri->slash_segment(1, 'leading') == $key ? 'class="active"' : '');
            $output .= "</li>".PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: with this one i get 
FATAL ERROR: USING $THIS WHEN NOT IN OBJECT CONTEXT IN for the $this->uri

Comment: This works like a charm except that I don't get the main menu header for the submenu's like "test" has now to contain these menu's when hovering on them bar and qux because right now i just get only the submenu's

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you said, could you explain the problem a little more clear? what do you mean by `I don't get the main menu header`?

Comment: it has to be like this 
<li><a href="#">test</a>
        <ul>
            <li>boo</li>
        </u>
    </li>
But i dont get 'test' right now

Comment: @Reshad `$value` for sub-menus is an array, If the `test` should be the URL address, and the `$value` should be the sub-menu items, where is the sub-menu header?? Do sub-menus have a link in their header? or `test` is the header of the sub-menu?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34913/discussion-between-reshad-and-hashem-qolami)

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion to do that job. It takes a bit of getting your head around if you're not familiar with it, but it's very well suited to this kind of problem.

I haven't run this code in PHP, but it will give you an idea.

Basically what happens is that the main menu function checks each item to see if it's an array, and then calls the function again using the sub menu. This will work infinitely deep if required.

```
<?php
  $menu = array(
      '/' => 'Home',
      '/about' => 'About',
      '/foo' => 'boo',
      '/contact' => 'contact',
      'test' => array(
                 'foo' => 'boo'
                ),

      'test2' => 'foo2'
  );
?>

<ul>
  <?php showMenu($menu); ?>
</ul>


<?php
  function showMenu($menu)
  {
    <?php foreach ($menu_item as $menu =>& $key): ?>    
      <li><?php echo anchor($menu, $key, $this->uri->slash_segment(1, 'leading') == $menu ? 'class="active"' : '') ?></li>
      if(is_array($menu_item))
      {
        echo "<ul>";
        showMenu($menu_item);
        echo "</ul>";
      }
    <?php endforeach ?>
  }
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt work i get a error syntax error, unexpected end of file in file... on line 48. there is something wrong with the function I found few things that were not correct but even after fixing the rest is results in this error

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the *$key* is an array: [is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php)

Then you can use another *foreach* to loop through the submenus.

Comment: Don't use another `foreach`, but rather make a recursive call!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<ul>
<?php function buildmenu($menu_item){ ?>
    <?php foreach($menu_item as $item){ ?>
            <li><?php echo anchor($menu, $key, $this->uri->slash_segment(1, 'leading') == $menu ? 'class="active"' : '') ?></li>
            <?php if(is_array($item)){ 
                    buildmenu($item); 
            } ?>
    <?php } ?>
<php} ?>
<?php buildmenu($menu_item) ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$menu = "<ul>\n";
foreach ($menu_item as $key => $value){
    if (is_array($value)){
        $menu.= "\t<li>".$key."\n\t\t<ul>\n";
        foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2){
            $menu .= "\t\t\t<li>".$value2."</li>\n";
        }
        $menu.= "\t\t</u>\n\t</li>\n";
    } else {
        $menu .= "\t<li>".$value."</li>\n";
    }
}
$menu .= "</ul>";
echo $menu;
```

Output:

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>boo</li>
    <li>contact</li>
    <li>test
        <ul>
            <li>boo</li>
        </u>
    </li>
    <li>foo2</li>
</ul>
```